# YouTube Data API: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota, INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

The problem occurred when I was using a Python program to upload videos to YouTube.  I did not use it to upload for many days before this happened so it should not exceed the quota.  I tried many times and it had the same error.

The following is the error:

[RequestError] Server response:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
        "domain": "youtube.quota",
        "reason": "quotaExceeded",
        "debugInfo": "Code: 8; Description: ?metric=youtube.googleapis.com/default&limit=defaultPerDayPerProject&qs_error_code=INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: The code is long.  It is the same code as https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload.

Comment: please supply a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example we need to see your code not a link to another site with your code

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Taking into account [the DTOS docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies), it's very likely that you exceeded 90 days of inactivity w.r.t. your API credentials:

> **Inactivity**
>
> YouTube reserves the right to disable or curtail your access to, or use of, specific [YouTube API Services](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#definition-youtube-api-services) if your [API Project](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#definition-api-project) has been inactive for 90 consecutive days. For example, YouTube could revoke your [API Credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#definition-api-credentials), or reduce (or eliminate) your [API Project's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#definition-api-project) quotas for specific [YouTube API Services](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#definition-youtube-api-services). If your [API Client's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#definition-api-client) quota is reduced or eliminated, you may reapply for quota or a quota extension, and YouTube will review that application based on YouTube’s determination of your expected use of the [YouTube API Services](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#definition-youtube-api-services).

You may follow the official recommendations stated above by applying for a quota extension. For obtaining a quota extension you have to address Google directly. There's [this form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) that you'll have to fill in. Than wait for response -- which, according to the experience of users of this forum, doesn't arrive shortly.

Other option would be to just discard (delete) the current app from [Google's developers console](https://console.developers.google.com) and create a new one that will have assigned a new daily quota amount (of usually 10,000 units).

Comment: Inactivity deactivation is what seems to have happened to me. I created the project last year, but just getting to it now, my quota is 0. I created a new project, enabled the API, and now I have 10k quota. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, create a new project....ho hum...but it works!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and the solution is quite simple. You just need to create a new project on [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com), then generate a new key and replace the old key with the new one. The API will be usable again.