# YouTube Data API v3 shows quota 0 out of 0

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

I'm using YouTube Data API v3 to retrieve a video info (title, description, thumb) when a user pasted  the URL into my internal system. I started getting an 403 error about quota.

When I open Console Developers Dashboard, it shows 45 requests in the last 30 days (that system is not used all the time).

[image: dashboard showing 45 requests in the last 30 days]

When I click to get an overview from that API, under Quotas, my queries per day shows 0 without possibility of change that limit.

[image: Quotas overview]

I got a message at the top of the page to request more quota limit but when I follow that link the form tells my current limit is 0 and to require a new limit - which is 0! Can't proceed without any number greater than 0.

[image: quota changes form]

Does anyone knows if that is a bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Youtube Data API: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota, INSUFFICIENT\_TOKENS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211098/youtube-data-api-the-request-cannot-be-completed-because-you-have-exceeded-your)?

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behavior see issue [#211012781](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211012781)

> Hi. If you're seeing Queries per day quota set to 0 and the API is indeed enabled, then this means that your project’s access to YouTube Data API Service has been disabled.

> You should’ve received a notice via email regarding this action, which also contains the steps that need to be taken to regain the project’s access. But just in case you missed it, please fill out and submit the exceptions form below:

https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en