# Cant use YouTube API daily quota reduced to 0

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

I used the YouTube API to get the number of views of the video and displayed it on the management site, but I couldn't get it on 5/12.

When I check [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), YouTube Data API v3 is valid, but the `daily allocation is 0` as shown in the image below. Originally it should be 10000 here. It seems that the numerical value cannot be obtained due to this.

- Are there any factors that automatically reduce the value to 0?
- Is there a way to solve it?
- There is an icon that can be edited in Queries / day, but it cannot be edited.
- A new API key has been issued and can now be obtained when it is supported.

[image]

Comment: This question Does not need clarity it is in in fact a duplicate of [YouTube Data API v3 shows quota 0 out of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70707870/1841839)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YouTube Data API v3 shows quota 0 out of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65111801/youtube-data-api-v3-shows-quota-0-out-of-0)