# Youtube v3 API says I've exceeded my quota, but my usage is 0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Inside the application, we're just pulling the title of a video being attached to a "profile" in the application.  Once the user enters a Youtube URL, we're hitting:

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=[KEY]&part=snippet&id=[ID]`

This has worked for years, and is VERY low traffic. Google now says we've exceeded our quota, but when I go into the Cloud Console to view quota usage, there are literally 20 requests in the past 30 days, and my quota limits are set to something crazy like 3,000,000.

The other posts on here are in relation to uploading and creating certified apps.  we're not uploading videos, just retrieving titles from the snippet information, so there's no way we've exceeded quotas.

I tried disabling the API, re-enabling, issuing a new API key... but the result remains the same.

Comment: Most likely YouTube [disabled your project due to inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63211212/8327971). I'd recommend to contact Google directly via [its own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/) for to confirm this conjecture (or to refute it for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to let you know that you are not the only one to notice this craziness on Google's API platform. I have been dealing with the same issue as I have for many years been able to simply access the Snippets of my videos and display the video related data on my website.

I used to get 1,000 queries per day and now, all of a sudden, it appears that the "project" needs to be tied to a payment account.

[image]

This is so they can now charge you for the queries that you use. Of course, they're not going to tell you upfront how much a "batch" of queries will cost you; at least not until you link your account (payment method).

This can be found in the following location...

[image]

This is as far as I've been able to get because I'm just a poor boy from the sticks and can't afford to be paying for queries for data from a resource that I own.

I hope this helps to answer some of your questions anyway.

Hello again @LinuxGnut, I finally got it working. It turns out that once I set up the Billing account in my Google profile and linked it to my API account, I went about deleting everything backward.

1. I deleted all credentials from each of my projects.
2. Then I deleted all of my projects (one at a time). This is risky if you have a lot of projects because it told me I only had 7 project slots left. Fortunately, I only need about three for now.
   I finally got it working. It turns out that once I set up the Billing account in my Google profile and linked it to my API account, I went about deleting everything backward.
3. I deleted all credentials from each of my projects.
4. Then I deleted all of my projects (one at a time). This is risky if you have a lot of projects because it told me I only had 7 project slots left. Fortunately, I only need about three for now.
5. Then you might need to delete folders as well.
6. If you have an organization set up, you might want to stop there. I don't have one so I skipped that part.

So, what I'm left with is a Billing account linked to my Google payment account.

Now, I recreated a project, added the YouTube Data v3 API, created new credentials, added them to my application's configuration, and voila! I retrieved the data I needed for all of my YouTube Videos. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Well @LinuxGnut, I've been plugging away at this all day and still cant add any queries/day to my YouTube Data API calls. I went ahead and linked the project to a Billing account and as soon as I did that, I was locked out of even being able to select the Global option to edit the quota amount. So, linking to a billing account only served to make matters worst.