# YouTube video upload using PHP Data API v3 recently stopped working

Tags: youtube-api

We developed a video upload to YouTube several years ago (2013) that stopped working with a misleading error message, since the quota is not the issue, see error message:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
"domain": "youtube.quota",
"reason": "quotaExceeded"
}
]
}
}
```

Could it be that the permissions to upload videos (insert) are not working anymore for the same Google account due to the changes Google/YouTube made in 2020?
I am stuck and hope someone can tell me what the issue might be and how to fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: Most likely your project has been [disabled due to inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63211212/8327971).

Comment: It is still active and shows "In production", so I guess that can't be the reason, but thanks

Comment: You may well obtain official accounts from Google staff by opening an issue report on company's own [issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/). They have all the info at hand to confirm (or otherwise refute) my conjecture.

Comment: Thanks, already reported the issue officially to Google